# Examples where ostragodsky's method is needed for integrating rational functions

Tags: calculus, integration, reference-request

I found out about Ostragodsky's method for integrating rational functions and thought it was pretty cool. However, I have never encountered any examples where it seemed needed (rather than just performing polynomial long division).

Maybe this is because because I use books that aren't from the ex-soviet bloc and this method is less known outside of these countries, or is it not as useful as I thought? Anyway, I'm looking for some cool examples I can work through using it.

Comment: Have you seen the two examples here? http://www.nabla.hr/CL-IndefIntegralB2.htm

Comment: @MatthewConroy I have, thank you though. Googling around didn't lead to any exercise sheets or anything.